# Rails + Sinatra apps sharing sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, sinatra

I haven't found a good answer to this yet. How can I get my Rails app and Sinatra app (mounted in my Rails app's config.ru) to share a session successfully? If I visit my Sinatra app first, then the Rails app, I get an error like `undefined method sweep for {}:Hash`, presumably because Rails uses a custom subclass of Hash for storing session info, and Rack::Session::Cookie doesn't. My code so far:

**config.ru**

```
map "/" do
  run MyRailsApp::Application
end

map "/sinatra" do
  use Rack::Session::Cookie, 
      key: "_app_session",
      secret: "<SECRET_KEY>"

  run MySinatraApp
end
```

**config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```
MyRailsApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session'
```

**config/initializers/secret_token.rb**

```
MyRailsApp::Application.config.secret_token = "<SECRET_KEY>" # same as config.ru
```

Anything I've missed?

Comment: Are you using rack-flash (or some other flash implementation) in the Sinatra app?

Comment: I'm using sinatra-flash, yeah.

Comment: I _think_ what's happening is sinatra-flash is adding a (normal, Ruby) hash to the session under the "flash" key. Rails expects whatever's under that key to be an `ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash` object, and tries to call the `sweep` method on it, hence the error `undefined method sweep for {}:Hash`. A possible work around might be to use a different key in the Sinatra app for the flash rather than the default (e.g. `flash(:my_flash)[:error]="foo"`). That won't help if you want to use the flash to see messages when going between Rails and Sinatra though.

Comment: That would definitely be okay - I don't plan on passing flash messages around. I'll try that and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Yep, that was definitely it. Thanks a ton. If you make an answer I can mark it as right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick `grep` of the Rails source reveals `sweep` is a method on `ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash`, which Rails stores in the session under the `flash` key.

Sinatra-Flash also uses the `flash` key of the session, but it stores a plain `Hash` object there.

Rails is getting the object at `session['flash']`, which is the `Hash` put there by Sinatra, assuming it is a `FlashHash` and trying to call `sweep` on it, hence the error message: `undefined method sweep for {}:Hash`.

A possible work around might be to use a different key in the Sinatra app for the flash rather than the default (e.g. `flash(:my_flash)[:error]="foo"`).

That won't help if you want to use the flash to see messages when going between Rails and Sinatra though.

Answer (score 0):

The "undefined method sweep for {}:Hash" issue is with your browser storing previously cached cookies. Just delete the cookies related to the application and refresh the browser. It worked for me.