# Rails and Sinatra shared session not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to share session between a Rails 3.2 application and a Sinatra application but it isn't working. If I go to `domain.com/rails` and log in, it logs in successfully. Then I go to `domain.com/sinatra` and the session clearly hasn't been shared. Also after that, if I try to access `domain.com/rails` again, I have been somehow logged out. Any ideas as to why this might not be working or why I'm getting logged out by accessing the sinatra app?

**config/initializers/secret_token.rb**

```rb
secret_file_path = "#{Rails.root}/session_key"
secret_key = "SECRET_KEY"
if File.exist? secret_file_path
  secret_key = File.read(secret_file_path).chomp
end
Wtf::Application.config.secret_token = secret_key
```

**config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```rb
Wtf::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'KEY_NAME'
```

**config.ru**

```rb
require "rack/jekyll"

builder = Rack::Builder.new do
  map '/' do
    run Rack::Jekyll.new(destination: '/_site')
  end

  require ::File.expand_path('/rails/config/environment',  __FILE__)

  map "/rails" do
    run RAILSAPP::Application
  end

  require '/sinatra_app/app.rb'

  map "/sinatra" do
    secret_file_path = '/rails/session_key'
    secret_key = "SECRET_KEY"
    if File.exist? secret_file_path
      secret_key = File.read secret_file_path
    end
    use Rack::Session::Cookie, key: "KEY_NAME",
                           secret: secret_key
    run SinatraApp
  end
end

run builder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a little too simple but might your sinatra secret_key just have a trailing newline character or something?
You call chomp in the rails example but not in the sinatra example.

N.B. watch out for [using flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135236/rails-sinatra-apps-sharing-sessions) if you get it working

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. That fixed it. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Ahh, brilliant, I was worried I was pointing out the obvious, glad I could help.